# ReactJS clearing textarea value after running a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, textarea

I have the following code for adding a comment into a table

```
const [newComment, setNewComment] = useState('')

<textarea onChange={e => setNewComment(e.target.value)} placeholder='Add a comment'/>

<button onClick={() => AddComment(newComment)}>Add</button>
```

After I click on the button to add a comment, I would like the textarea value to clear/reset to the original placeholder 'Add a comment'. Currently after I press the button, the comment gets added however the textarea retains the 'newComment" value meaning I then have to manually clear it before I insert a new comment which is not very convenient - any suggestions?

Comment: Can you use input instead of textarea?

Comment: If there is a way to make it work with input then yes - please could you provide the code snippet?

Comment: I updated my code snippet with input

Comment: Thank you, it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. After you press a button you set the value to empty string

```js
const [newComment, setNewComment] = useState('')

<input value={newComment} onChange={e => setNewComment(e.target.value)} placeholder='Add a comment'/>

<button onClick={() => {
  AddComment(newComment)
  setNewComment('')
 }}>Add</button>
```

Comment: I've tried this method, doesn't do anything different to the textarea value

Comment: @Anurag Srivastava it will works with textarea same

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to make the textarea what React calls a "controlled component" by giving it a `value` attribute that reflects the `newComment` state:

```
  const [newComment, setNewComment] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <textarea
        onChange={e => setNewComment(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Add a comment"
        value={newComment}
      />

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          AddComment(newComment)
          setNewComment("");
        }}
      >
        Add
      </button>
    </div>
  );
```